# how to match "=3" with word boundary in java?

Tags: java, regex

I want to match an independent word of `=3`, but the word boundary `\b` doesn't work. How do I modify the following java code?

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b=3\\b");
String x = " =3 ";
System.out.println(pattern.matcher(x).replaceAll("something"));
```

Currently, above code cannot replace `=3` with `something`

Comment: Can you please describe the word boundary you need to match? What can go before = so that it should match? Try `\\B=3\\b`.

Comment: What do you want the code to do with `==3`?  Is the `=3` substring considered an independent word within `==3`?  If not, then several of the answers, including the accepted answer [that is, the accepted answer at the time I started this comment], are wrong.  The problem is that you haven't really defined for us what your idea of an "independent word" is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to achieve this with the following regex;

```
(^\B=3\b|(\s)\B=3\b)
```

Forcing it to insert a boundary before `=` sign, and ignoring other boundary creating chars with a `\s`, and also a case for the beginning of the line captures with `^`.

So for an input

```
=3 one =3 ==3 .=3 two =3a a=3
```

replacement with `"$2something"` will result

```
"something one something ==3 .=3 two =3a a=3"
```

see it in action [here](http://rextester.com/CYFL14299)

`$2` in the replacement value is to keep `\s` space value in its original location, and not to break anything with the original string but isolated `=3` instances.

Comment: If the string is `"==3"`, this will change it to `"=something"`.  Is this what the OP wants?  If he's considering `==3` to be a word, then this answer is wrong.

Comment: It works! thanks! But I don't quite understand. \B match "Not-a-word-boundary", right, according to http://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#notb ? how come it matches the space before "=3"?

Comment: @ajb you are right, I think currently `\B` works by disabling the boundary of the `=` at the beginning of the `=3`, and pushing it one char to the left. Since the space before `=` in `=3` is not matched by `\B`, can be seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/4tzRoL/2). The trouble can be fixed by using `\s\B(=3)\b` to eliminate any other matches but the negation of this boundary, just like your examples. But then if this word were to be at the beginning, it wouldn't be matched. hmm

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\B=3\\b");
```

Note `\B` instead of `\b` at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

a lookbehind seems to work

```
String x = " 8=3 =3 a=3 =3d =3 =3";
x = x.replaceAll("(?<!\\b)=3\\b", "something");
System.out.println(x);
```

**output**

8=3 something a=3 =3d something something

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I'm not mistaken, but I believe you can just do the following:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\B=3\\b");
```

I've tested it and it **does** replace `=3` with `something`, but there might be cases where this doesn't work.

Please let me know if there's a specific use-case that you want, and I'll see what I can do!

Comment: Thanks, but this way will match "=3"  which is part of a word, like "8=3". I need a match of an independent word "=3". I find the problem is from "\b" before "=", it cannot match the space before "=3" in the string x.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking.  If you're wondering if this will turn `8=3` into `8something`, it will.  If that's not what you're asking, what is an example of a `String` containing `=3`, and what do you want to replace it?

Comment: for example, x="8=3 =3 8\t=3" . I want to get "8=3 something 8\tsomething".
the first =3 should not be replaced, because 8 is not a word boundary.

Comment: Oh, so you only want to replace it if it's not part of a word?

Comment: Yeah, I want to match an independent word "=3", separated by word boundaries.

Comment: @Ming Should be good now!  Check this out for more information: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html